# Typescript Nested Observables

Tags: typescript, rxjs6

Background:
Using rxjs Observables

I'm trying to call a method (with an observable) that calls another method.  This current setup isn't working for me  with the following compilation error in checkIfTrue function in service 1...

> A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return
>   a value.ts(2355)

```
//component
//makes call to service
process = () => {
     this.service1.checkIfTrue().subscribe(x => {console.log(x)});
};

//service 1
//makes call to service 2
checkIfTrue = (): Observable<boolean> => {
     this.service2.getInt().subscribe(y => { return y == 1;});
};


//service 2
//makes call to service 2
getInt = (): Observable<number> => {
     return Observable.of(1);
};
```

It seems like I can't return the response from the second method...How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
checIfTrue (): Observable<boolean> => {
     this.service2.getInt().subscribe(y => { return y == 1;});
};
```

You have two functions here:

- checkIfTrue()
- y => { return y == 1; }

Your second function has a return statement, your checkIfTrue() has no return statement. That's why it does not return a value. Just as an example, that should make clear why that cannot work:

```
// y => y == 1 function dummy
function a() {
  return true;
}

// subscribe() dummy
function b(callback: Function) {
  callback();
}

function checkIfTrue() {
  // your subscribe(y => y == 1) line
  b(a);
}
```

What you're looking for is something like this

```
checIfTrue (): Observable<boolean> => {
   return this.service2.getInt()
    .pipe(map(y => y == 1));
};
```

You can shorten this as:

```
checIfTrue (): Observable<boolean> => this.service2
    .getInt()
    .pipe(map(y => y == 1));
```

Comment: Thanks, but you are combining my two methods into one, this is not what I want....  I know how to do it that way! What do you mean by "checkIfTrue has no return statement"

Comment: y => { return y == 1; } is a separate function, it's what I tried to demo with my "a" function. Only this function has a return statement, your checkIfTrue function has no return statement and without a return statement it will not return a value and that's what the compiler error tells you.